# Role-Based login in nodejs and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have an application with 2 roles, a **User** and a **Photographer**. the difference between these 2 models is a **isAdmin field in User** and a **Photo[ ] in Photographer** and a **order[ ] in User**. But I need only one login for both of them! Clearly, need different views and routs for them! how can I do this? If any guide, I would be appreciated! Thanks a lot!

The schemas are as below:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    //some other fields, the same with photographer
    isAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    orders: [{
        price: { type: Number, default: 0 }
        },
        {timestamps: true}
    ]
});

var photographerSchema = new Schema({
    //some other fields, the same with user
    photos: [{
        title: { type: String, default: '' },
        path: { type: String },
        price: { type: Number, default: 0 },
        isAppoved: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        },
    {timestamps: true}
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rethink your architecture. Better solution would be to have 1 `User` model and 2 `profile` submodels. `User` model would contain the `type`  of the user and fetch profile info(writer_profile/user_profile) from the submodels.

If you won't refactor, this will turn in to a mess pretty fast. Think about it, what happens when a `User` and a `Writer` registers with the same credentials? You will need to check that too.

Comment: Thanks for attention! Do you mean I merge these two models and add a field like this: isPhotographer :{ type : Boolean} in User and when logged in, check the role using 2 if statements ?? Thanks!

Comment: No, just add `userType: "Photographer"/"User"`. And then add another field `Profile: { custom stuff here }`. And then yes, just check user type with if statement and use appropriate data.

Comment: Thanks again for you answer, but one thing is ambiguous, what is this `Profile` field? Thanks! @IvRRimUm

Comment: Its the place you store all profile specific stuff. Like isAdmin and Photo[], etc.

Comment: Ahaaa. Thank you a lot for your guide.